# python name regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Am trying to match a name in the pattern "FirstnameSpaceLastname" e.g John Doe, just the first and last name with a space in between, how can I go about it? the code is below shows what i.ve tried:

```
user_input = input("Enter you full names: ")
def valid_name():
    #name_regex = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z\\sa-zA-Z]$')
    #name_regex = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]$')
    #name_regex = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z a-zA-Z]+$')
    #name_regex = re.compile('^a-zA-Z\sa-zA-Z$')    
    name_regex = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z a-zA-Z]$')
    nameMatch = re.match(name_regex, user_input)
    if nameMatch:
        print(user_input)
    else:
        print('Enter name in (Firstname Lastname) format')

valid_name()
```

Comment: This `[a-zA-Z a-zA-Z]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z ]` (Note that names can have a great variety in length and characters)

Comment: Does `r"(\w+)\s+(\w+)"` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```py
^[^\W\d_]+\s[^\W\d_]+\Z
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/pSGMDf/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\W\d_]+                any character of: letters/diacritics (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\W\d_]+                any character of: letters/diacritics (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to compile:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+
```

?

About @JonSG's comentary: `\w` is for any alphanumeric. Replace it with `a-zA-Z` if you need only letters.